# How can I conditionally format a cell in a sheet if and only if the same cell in another sheet has a value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got two sheets that have the same structure, where the first is a list of a certain kind of object and the second is there to augment the first one.

I want to format the second sheet so that if Sheet1!B2 has a value (is not blank), then Sheet2!B2 is shown with one format, and if Sheet1!B2 does NOT have a value (is blank), then Sheet2!B2 has a different format.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a conditional format rule on Sheet2 cell B2. This will format that cell if Sheet 1 B2 is blank.

```
=ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2)
```

If you're trying to do this with multiple cells, then highlight the entire range in Sheet 2, and then input this formula as your Conditional Format Rule:

```
=ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2)
```

This will look at the same cells in Sheet 1. Just make sure to appropriately highlight the range when creating the conditional format rule.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]